# Using ".value" of an <input> element works when run as Dart, fails when compiled to JavaScript

Tags: dart

This question has *mostly* been answered elsewhere, but I thought I would mention my experience with this because of an interesting side-effect the Dart guys might be interested in knowing.

```
  enterPinDigits() {
      Element pinDigits = document.getElementById('pinDigits');
      pinDigits.value = "";
```

In the above, `pinDigits` is an HTML input element. When I code it as above, the editor tells me it doesn't recognize `value` as a valid field for the element.

HERE'S THE WEIRD PART:
This code behaves perfectly fine running in the Chromium/Dart environment, but it fails horribly when compiled to Javascript. Odd inconsistency.

Comment: Based on the answers, I'd say this is a bug. Type annotations are not supposed to change runtime behaviour at all; and it sounds like in this case they are?!

Comment: I could not reproduce. Could you please verify if this still happens on the latest version, and, if yes, file a bug with a reproducible example. Thanks.

Comment: In the latest (1.4.3) I am not seeing the inconsistent behavior. Storing the reference to the input element as an "Element" still causes the editor to complain and still causes a warning in the console, but the code itself appears to work in both Dart and JS environments now. 

No setter named 'value' in class 'Element'.
      if (digitsEntered == 0) { pinDigits.value = ""; }
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Warning from Dart2JS on timeline|web/timeline_web.dart]:
No member named 'value' in class 'Element'.
      pinDigits.value += "*";
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` returns a `Node` and the DartEditor can't know that it has an attribute `value` unless you state that it is an `InputElement`. If you make the variable of type `Element` it still has no `value` attribute.

```dart
var pinDigits = document.getElementById('pinDigits') as InputElement;
```

or

```dart
InputElement pinDigits = document.getElementById('pinDigits');
```

this way you also get proper autocompletion.

Dart2js uses type information for tree-shaking. It might drop the wrong code because of the wrong type annotation. In this case no type (`var`) is better than the wrong type. Actually `Element` isn't wrong so it might still be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand that this should be an `InputElement`, but I also found that a quick solution is to simply change the variable type from the Darty `Element` type to a generic `var`.

```
  var pinDigits = document.getElementById('pinDigits');
```

But as this subject has been somewhat addressed elsewhere, this post is mostly meant to clarify the earlier post and to point out the odd inconsistency when running as Dart vs Javascript.